# Entity Framework Circular Reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Trying this question again because my first attempt was barely coherent :p

So I am super confused and using Entity Framework Code First

I have a Forest class.

I have a Tree class.

Each Forest can have many Trees

When I was trying to serialize I was getting circular reference

```
public class Forest
{

    public Guid ID { get; set; }  
    public virtual List<Tree> Trees { get; set; }
}
public class Tree
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid? ForestId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("ForestId")]
    public virtual Forest Forest {get;set;}
 }
```

Every forest has trees but not every tree is in a forest.  I struggle with either errors of Multiplicity when doing

```
@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))
```

Where the model is a Forest

and if I make `ForestId` a `Guid` instead of a `Guid?` I get Circular Reference errors.

I also tried 
protected override void

```
OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
  modelBuilder.Entity<Forest>() 
  .HasMany(x => x.Tree) 
  .WithOptional() 
   .HasForeignKey(y => y.ForestId); 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using DataContractSerializer? If so, I don't see your DataContracts, but you would need to set IsReference=true.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Best approach would be you should use DTOs to transfer only the data that you want to the client. The DTOs should have just simple properties so it won't create a circular reference error. At the moment the Forest has `List<Trees> Trees`  and each `Tree` within Trees has `Forest` and that `Forest` again has `List<Trees>`

**Or**

You can decorate your attributes with `ScriptIgnore` for properties that you don't want the 
Json.Encode to serialize and then that wouldn't be sent back to the client.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx

Eg:

```
public class Forest
{    
    public Guid ID { get; set; }  
    public virtual List<Tree> Trees { get; set; }
}
public class Tree
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid? ForestId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("ForestId")]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual Forest Forest {get;set;}
 }
```

**Edit:**

Along with `ScriptIgnore` you should also remove `virtual` from `Forest` and `Trees` and that would work. I've tested it. However, I wouldn't advise that because virtual keyword is what does the Lazy loading. Hence as I said you need to create DTOs based on these Models and only send in DTO to client.

Comment: Even with Script ignore it gave me circular reference so I looked at the model.  ID field for the Tree keeps drilling down as does the ID field for the Forest.
I am using GUIDs generated in the database using NewId() could this be causing my problem?  I even set Trees = null in Forest and it is still giving a circular reference.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I ended up realizing last night I could take the virtual off.  I realize it isn't the ideal solution but I'm just prototyping for this project so in this instance it is fine.  In future production work I will indeed use DTOs!

Thank you very much!