# EF - how to prevent eager loading to load all nested entities

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I've manay-to-many relationship between two entities: Categories <--> Items

```
public class CategoryMaster
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<SubCategoryMaster> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public List<ItemMaster> Items { get; set; } 
}

public class ItemMaster
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryMaster> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I try to explicit load related items to all/certain categories, it gives me

- all related items
- related categories to those items
- related items to those categories and so on...nested/circular references

  ```
     db.CategoryMaster
          .Include(x=>x.Items)
          .Include(x=>x.SubCategories.Select(y=>y.Items))
          .ToList();
  ```

Hence results in below error while serializing it to JSON on *.cshtml with Json.Encode();

```
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'GoGreen.Data.Entities.SubCategoryMaster'.
```

Since I've disabled the lazy loading at property level, I'm not expecting it to load all nested entities(circular references) at any point of time. Is there a way to load all related level one records i.e. Categories and related items.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811975/entity-framework-circular-reference) - But Iodon't want to go with any of the two ways suggested.

**NOTE** : I'm more interested in knowing why EF behaves like this. It seems a bug to me.

Comment: check the answer and tell me if that helped you or not.

Comment: You should replace the json serializer by Json.Net and set reference loop handling.

Answer (score 0):

First approach: you can add attribute above properties you don't want to exclude it from being serialized using `[ScriptIgnore]`, you can create partial class and add your customization if your entities are auto generated

Second approach: Create a Model with only properties you need in your view and select only this model and set your properties

```
EFcontext.Tabel.include(x=>x...).Select(x=>new MyModel { ... });
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this approach, but I won't prefer doing this as I'm expecting some fix in EF framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround, and please don't kill me :-) After object loading and before serializing, just set the loaded objects which are causing the circular reference to `null`. I tried it and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

use meta data redirection. figured I would help anyone who stumbled here.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CategoryMasterMetadata))]
public partial class CategoryMaster
{
}


public class CategoryMasterMetadata
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<SubCategoryMaster> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public List<ItemMaster> Items { get; set; } 
}
```